# Point or Redirect one domain to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two domains on AWS. one with .eu and another with .fr I have also hosted site on .eu domain. Now I want to use .fr instead of .eu. when user type domain with .fr or .eu it should load the site of .eu
How can I do this? I am using Route 53 and AWS EC2.

Comment: See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-rules-managing.html

Comment: What do you mean by "have also hosted site on .eu domain"? Do you mean that your .eu DNS Name contains an A-Record that points to an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Yes

Comment: Can't you just configure your .fr domain to resolve in exactly the same way as your .eu domain (with the same A-Record configuration)?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I have added A record for .fr domain as I did for .eu domain but not resolving

Comment: It can take some time for changes to propagate. If it has been more than a day, then something is wrong with your configuration. Woud you like to tell us your domain names, and how you have configured them?

Comment: Basically I have transferred my eotrace.fr domain from ionos to AWS and it transferred successfully, Now I have created a hosted zone and put A record in eotrace.fr of my instance IP. Now the eotrace.eu and eotrace.fr have same IP/A Record.

Comment: It is more than one day and when i check my domain name on whois it shows old name server records.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to perform a redirect on your `.eu` domain. There are several ways you can do this:

- Deploy a CloudFront Distribution in front, add a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) function.
- Use an ALB [redirect rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) based on host header.
- Add a redirect to your host instance either in code or via the web server software.

Whichever solution you choose, you will need to then point your hostname at that endpoint so that the redirect will occur.